# Translations for 'instead'

Tags: traduction, locutions-adverbiales

I'm having trouble translating 'instead' into French.  Suppose I write:

> Unfortunately, my questions in no way shed any light on the numerous
> questions that historians have wanted answered.  Instead I asked him
> if he etc etc.

Admittedly, some native speakers of English might even object that I'm not using the word 'instead' correctly, but I think it's correct for the following reasons.  You can say "instead of x, I did y" where x is the thing you should have done, but you did y instead.  So in this sentence above, I should have asked a good question but instead I asked a stupid one.

I'm aware of 'au lieu de', but it doesn't feel right to me in this context.

Comment: I think the most literal translation (but perhaps not the best) would be "à la place"

Comment: You translated "shed" as past tense in a comment below. Why do you say "I *should* have asked a good question but..." if you actually asked it? This makes me think there's more to that "instead" than a conscious choice not to do something. It's more of a regretful second-best thing after trying the first, right?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking but 'should' here would be used in the sense of: I should have done x, but I did y, which is to say, under normal circumstances rational person p does x, but p had a momentary lapse of reason and did y instead.  I'm pretty sure it would be the same in French.  Normalement, une personne rationnelle p fait x, mais p a eu un manque momentané de raison, et à la place, il a fait z, c'est-à-dire, il a dû faire x, mais il a fait z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Par contre*, je lui ai demandé si...

*En revanche* n'est pas mal non plus dans ce cas.

Tu as raison, *au lieu de* se suit par une autre phrase nominale ou une phrase de même catégorie, ce n'est pas pour changer la proposition.  « Utiliser de la levure alimentaire au lieu de fromage ou du sel, »  par exemple.  « Au lieu de poser de telles questions, je lui ai demandé...», ça se peut mais il y a beaucoup de répétition et ça fait moins simple, moins clair.

> « Par contre », formé d’une préposition et d’un adverbe, attesté dès le XVIe siècle, « est entré dans l’usage général, même le plus exigeant, au cours du XIXe siècle, malgré la résistance des puristes » (« Le Bon usage », § 965, e 4°) suivant Voltaire et Littré et il est très employé, y compris par les écrivains.  Le rejeter dans le « langage commercial » est artificiel.

> Car leur sens n’est pas exactement le même : « en revanche » véhicule
> une idée d’échange, de rétablissement d’équilibre, « en retour, en
> compensation, en contrepartie » ; « par contre » marque plus nettement
> l'opposition, notamment à un énoncé antérieur.

[Grevisse.fr](https://www.grevisse.fr/le-blog-chroniques-grevisse/norme-et-usage/par-contre-en-revanche#:%7E:text=Car%20leur%20sens%20n%27est,notamment%20%C3%A0%20un%20%C3%A9nonc%C3%A9%20ant%C3%A9rieur.) (le blog)

Comment: Other usual translation option : "Je lui ai *plûtot* demandé ..."

Comment: @Graffito Oui, j'avais pensé à celle-là aussi, j'aurais du la mettre.

Comment: Les puristes voient peut-être une différence entre _en revanche_ et _par contre_, mais dans l'usage courant, ils sont plutôt interchangeables, pour le meilleur ou pour le pire.

Comment: thanks I appreciate that, especially the link to Grevisse which seems to have some good articles

Comment: @Frank —  L'usage courant ne saurait avoir de valeur normative, surtout de nos jours. Il convient alors de résister au pire, itaque de s'en remettre toujours à Vaugelas, s'agissant de comprendre l'esprit de notre langue.

Comment: @BriceC. Ça tombe bien alors, parce qu'on n'a pas besoin de _valeur normative_, surtout du 17e siècle.

Comment: @Frank Je suis d'accord. 
 L'article nous dit aussi que pour ce premier, *Le rejeter dans le « langage commercial » est artificiel.*. Je suis d'accord, tout est artificiel.

Comment: @BriceC. The goal of the site is descriptive. One might ask what people in a given place and time said and what they meant by it, or how the Académie decided on a given spelling, or what Grévisse meant by a given rule, or even how to apply the latter to a given real case. But the goal is not to reject as chaotic the spontaneous grammar of everyday life. It's primarily the description of language, not of a system of linguistic legislation — even a beautiful, brilliant, and often useful legislation. You can engage in such a project or not, but don't butt heads with those who do. Merci.

Comment: @LukeSawczak — When endeavouring to learn a foreign language, your guideline ought to be: 'Learn it properly'. I suspect you are no French native speaker, though truly capable of reading French. Therefore my best advice is, think over the meaning of the title of M. Grevisse's Grammaire française —Le Bon Usage, i.e. what those  'qui ont le souci de bien parler' care for, in other words:  'those who care about speaking correctly'.  I have no clue about your background, but whatever it might be you will agree that no knowledge is owed without studying hard.

Comment: @BriceC. Il est question de ce qu'on étudiera plutôt que de la rigueur des études : langage en tant que produit de processus naturels ou en tant que système consciemment élaboré. En tout cas, je ne te dis que le but du site dont je suis élu modérateur (il y en a trois), et je te prie de ne pas sermonner les autres membres qui poursuivent ce but. Tu pourrais t'informer sur ce si tu voudrais, ou même proposer un changement, en rédigeant une question sur [le site méta](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @LukeSawczak — C'est une très bonne idée que d'intervenir sur le site méta. J'entends le faire prochainement et, au vu des réactions obtenues, déciderai si ce site  répond à mes attentes. Je vous remercie de votre suggestion.

Comment: @BriceC. Oui, mais, si Vaugelas avait l'intention de fixer _le bon usage_ en faisant référence aux pratiques de l'élite (et de la cour, ce qui le mettait sans doute dans les bonnes grâces de ceux qui comptaient), _Le Bon Usage_ de Grevisse et maintenant Goose répond justement à Vaugelas avec des principes différents et énumérés dans l'introduction de la 12e édition par exemple: "_solidité de son information sur la langue réelle_", et "_modération de ses jugements normatifs_" entre autres. Grevisse et Goose ont bien compris qu'on ne peut pas contraindre une langue vivante avec quelques règles.

Comment: Quant à Vaugelas, quel que fût son mérite au 17e siècle - c'est bien loin quand même! - on ne peut raisonnablement se faire le chantre d'un retour à ce qu'il préconisait exactement, bien sûr, mais même sa "méthode" (prendre pour référence "la façon de parler de la plus saine partie de la Cour, [...] la façon d'escrire de la plus saine partie des Autheurs du temps"), ne semble plus correspondre à notre époque moderne - comment échapper à l'arbitraire dans une définition moderne de ce qui est le plus _sain_ dans la langue?

Comment: @Frank, c'est toujours pour moi que tu fais ces remarques ou poses cette question ? 
Ça devient difficile comme ces commentaires s'éloignent de la réponse et méritent peut-être une autre question.  Ou de la conversation en tchat Chez Cosette.

Comment: @livresque Pardon, désolé. C'était pour Brice C.

Answer (score 2):

S'acharner à trouver une traduction lexicale directe à *instead* relève ici d'une maladresse de jeune traducteur. C'est à la stylistique qu'on doit se référer ; et la réponse tombe sous forme d'une consécutive, laquelle exprimera parfaitement l'intention du locuteur au vu de la phrase précédente :

> *Aussi* lui ai-je demandé (…) (ou « lui demandai-je »… à préciser).

N.B.: Curieusement, l'existence de la conjonction de coordination "aussi" est attestée dans le Larousse en trois volumes (1970), mais non dans le Trésor de la Langue française, qui ne voit dans ce mot qu'un adverbe.

Comment: What about in formal writing?  My language exchange partner kept crossing out 'aussi' and replacing it with 'egalement'.

Comment: In this context, aussi means "consequently" and is, on the contrary, a very formal use of the word. An alternative is "partant". The proposed answer seems to be that, insted of expressing an opposition with the previous sentence, you present the subsequent questioning as a consequence of the lacunary answers.

Comment: Il serait intéressant de savoir en foi de quoi je suis désapprouvé dans mon intervention… Amusant aussi, compte tenu de mon passé professionnel.

Comment: @bobsmith76 — It is high time your 'language exchange partner' reviewed his basic knowledge of French.

Comment: Well, they're a native speaker, so you'd have to see the exact instances where 'aussi' was crossed out in favor of 'egalement', but those instances have been forgotten.

Comment: Uh! It is all much clearer now. I first thought that that "aussi" referred to your initial example. Most times "aussi" has, as an adverb, the meaning of "également". But beware: a good many native French speakers will prefer "également" simply because it sounds more correct to their ears — while being often just pedantic waffle.

Comment: +1. This should be the accepted answer, as the other ones seem to have misinterpreted "shed" as a present of general truth: *Mes questions n'éclairent pas (en général) // A la place j'ai demandé...* but *Mes questions n'ont pas éclairé... // Aussi lui ai-je demandé (pour finir/par dépit)...*

Comment: @guillaume31 — Nice to see you have a foot in both French and English. What an awesome word 'shed' is — think of 'watershed' as 'bassin versant'.

Comment: @Brice, regarding natives using the word 'également' to sound in intelligent sort of in the way that anglophones will use 'thus', 'therefore' or 'indeed' in order to sound intelligent, can you give an example.  This is interesting.

Comment: @ also, I don't know what your native language, but thanks for using the expression 'it's high time' since it's one of my favorites in English.

Answer (score 0):

Mes tentatives:

> Malheureusement, mes questions n'éclairent en aucun cas les nombreux points sur lesquels les historiens ont cherché des réponses. À la place, je lui ai demandé...

> Malheureusement, mes questions n'éclairent en aucun cas les nombreux points sur lesquels les historiens ont cherché des réponses. En fait, je lui ai demandé...

Je suis conscient qu'il est un peu étrange qu'une question *éclaire* en général (ne serait-ce pas plutôt une *réponse* qui *éclaire*?), mais j'ai voulu rester proche de l'original. En revanche, j'ai remplacé le deuxième "*questions*" par *points* pour éviter une répétition. Je ne crois pas que ces petites difficultés aient un impact réel sur la substance de la question ("au lieu de").

Comment: It was the narration of a dream I had where I met Hitler. Suppose you met Hitler and you had an opportunity to ask him some questions.  If you asked him some good questions and he had no reason to lie, you might improve your understanding of history.  Here's my translation: Malheureusement, mes questions n’ont mises en lumière en aucune façon sur les plus troublantes mystères de notre époque qui seul Hitler pourrait résoudre, à la place je lui ai demandé s’il conduisait un char lors de la première guerre mondiale.

Comment: @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t, you're right, I never thought of that, thanks for the info.

Comment: re: [Holocaust Encyclopedia](https://encyclopedia.ushmm.org/content/en/article/adolf-hitler). Welcome! @bobsmith76